# Is there an accepted naming scheme for

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, language-agnostic

I'm working on a framework for game development in flash and I'm wondering if there's an accepted naming scheme for the main tick / update method name and a name for the functions to call before and after?

I can think of:

```
onPreTick(), onTick() and onPostTick()
onPreFrame(), onFrame(), and onPostFrame()
onPreUpdate(), onUpdate(), and onPostUpdate()
```

Is there some accepted term for what I'm trying to convey?

Comment: I have added flash and AS3 tag, assuming that you are using AS3 though not specified in the question.

Answer (score 1):

For flash using `on` before event type names is quite standard practice, though that is not required in AS3. So `onFrame` is standard. Instead of `pre` and `post` you can use `before` and `after` too. And `tick` is also common in game loop. However you can use more specific term in `update`. For example, if you are updating only the physics then name it `updatePhysics`.

Comment: I would say that onUpdate, being less specific let's you implement a time based update approach or a frame based one and still being descriptive...

Answer (score 0):

Personally I follow the practice of using on[objectName][eventType] for naming my event handlers, for example:

```
var loader:Loader = new Loader();
loader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onLoaderComplete);
loader.load(new URLRequest(url));

function onLoaderComplete(e:Event):void {}
```

However if I were adding an event listener to an object in its class I would exclude the object name so that its more like on[eventType], for example:

```
public class CustomLoader extends Loader
{
    public function CustomLoader(url:String)
    {
        this.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onComplete);
        this.load(new URLRequest(url));
    }

    function onComplete(e:Event):void { }
}
```